# Write table row names problems in R

Tags: r, matrix, text, names

I'm using the `write.table()` method to write a matrix into a text file. My matrix has row and column names. I noticed that R messes up that names.

First of all names that start with a digit are wrote using `X` as prefix. For example `1005_at` will become `X1005_at`.

Second characters as `-` and `/` are substituted with a dot `.`.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to avoid this crazy issue?

Comment: R doesn't like it when you start your column names with a number

Comment: Check `make.names`. It's not a 'crazy issue'.

Comment: So there is no way to avoid this conversion?

Comment: You could work-around by creating your column names via `as.character`, or by simply writing text strings into your file and then appending your matrix sans header.

Comment: I actually have no problem writing column names to whatever I want (including starting with numbers, special characters `/`,`+`, etc). I think your problem is that when you created your data, you did not set `check.names = FALSE` so the columns were redefined from the get-go. You could change them back with `names(data) <- c('3//.-3', '423+3')` or whatever, and you'd have no problem with `write.table`

Comment: So, to answer your follow-up @Lazza87, yes: you can avoid the conversion in `read.csv` or `data.frame` by adding `check.names = FALSE`

Comment: Thanks, the easiest way is to set check.names = FALSE!

Answer (score 1):

`make.names` is used to convert names to syntactically valid ones. Check out this small example:

```
> make.names(c(".1 - / q", "if", "0", "NA"))
[1] "X.1.....q" "if."       "X0"        "NA."
```

The documentation says:

> A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or
>   underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed
>   by a number.
>   <...>
>   The character "X" is prepended if necessary. All invalid characters
>   are translated to "."